# Error while building Pixel experince 13 "Failed to resolve classcommon statement at out/....../plat_policy_for_vendor .cil:"

Tags: android-source, custom-rom, lineageos

```
[  0% 398/56578] //system/sepolicy:plat_policy_for_vendor.cil Building cil for plat_policy_for_vendor.cil [common]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil/android_common/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil
out/host/linux-x86/bin/checkpolicy -C -M -c 30 -o out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil/android_common/plat_policy_for
_vendor.cil out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/plat_policy_for_vendor.conf/android_common/plat_policy_for_vendor.conf && cat system/sepolicy/p
rivate/technical_debt.cil >>  out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil/android_common/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil && out/h
ost/linux-x86/bin/secilc -m -M true -G -c 30 out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil/android_common/plat_policy_for_vend
or.cil -o /dev/null -f /dev/null # hash of input list: 6e559a895c8d47ee372fecf016f5b2639b5d5d288a4777b8a065fc673afaa911
Failed to resolve classcommon statement at out/soong/.intermediates/system/sepolicy/plat_policy_for_vendor.cil/android_common/plat_policy_for_vendor
.cil:489
Failed to resolve AST
Failed to compile cildb: -2
15:54:17 ninja failed with: exit status 1
```

I am trying to build Pixel Experince 13 for my device Moto G6. No android 13 device trees are avalable for this device.

I am a noobie to rom building scene!

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hello prabhat, the best bet is to build Android 12 Based LineageOS 19.1 first, take those sources, move to permissive eng build and then start adapting patches for Android 13.

Comment: already build los19 and pe12